# I can’t get the “I do” dialogue during my marriage

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-hearthfire

I’ve been playing Skyrim for some time now, been bad, been good and been all of that but marriage is the one step I’ve yet to take.. so I decided to take it, I went to talk to Ulfric and we both agreed to have a wedding.. I went to talk to Marmal and he set the day to be tomorrow dusk till dawn. I arrive the next day (between 8am - 8pm) and marmal welcomes me and Ulfric is already there. He says all that he needs to say and asks if I’m willing to get married to Ulfric.. now here is when the problem begins, the dialogue for “I do” doesn’t pop up, instead we just stand there with Marmal’s hands raised and Ulfric checking me out now and then and I can’t move or anything .. it must be the wedding jitters. Anyone know how I can fix this?